# Same MediaWiki database/files on multiple subdomains

Tags: mediawiki

so I am currently setting up a MediaWiki server (I am still not sure whether I should go for MediaWiki or DokuWiki though), but if I go for MediaWiki - is it possible to setup some kind of multi MediaWiki?
Same installation on multiple subdomains.

I would like a main domain which could be wiki.com. For every product/category I would like it's own subdomain. Is it possible to use the same MediaWiki installation and then have iphone.wiki.com, android.wiki.com, windows.wiki.com etc.

Kind of like how wikia works now, I just want my domain/server.

Comment: This question is already answered on the following page with detailed instructions: [https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Wiki_family](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Wiki_family).

Answer (score 2):

It's definitely possible, I'm doing this with [wiki.yt](http://wiki.yt).

You need to know enough PHP to make sure that a different database is served to different (sub)domains. I started factoring out things from `LocalSettings.php` and I'm keeping an area with domains and settings.

(If I find some time I'll factor out some of the code and [open it up](https://github.com/guaka/wiki.yt-public/issues/6). I'll update this answer if I get there.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

An easier alternative is to simply install MediaWiki for each subdomain or folder. They would all have separate databases and duplicate source codes, but you could configure MediaWiki to have each of the instances of MediaWiki rely on common resources, like where the images are stored.

[See here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Wiki_family#Multiple_wikis_sharing_common_resources) for more information.